# How highlight view like listview in android

Tags: android, view

I use my view instead of ListView. How can I highlight this view on touch like it highlighting  in ListView on touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a selector as a background for your view.
For example:
selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
```

someOther.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<yourView
    android:id="@+id/viewWithSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector.xml" />
```